# Python - count the number of sundays on the first day of month between two dates

Tags: python-3.x

I need to calculate the number of sundays by importing calendar, but I don't have a clue on how to determine if those sundays are on the first day of the month. Any guide please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard `datetime` module. Here is a very simple naive algorithm to approach your problem: 
1) Get the starting and ending dates to look between them 
2) Iterate on all dates between the given two (using the date's ordinal)
3) Check whether or not it is Sunday first usind `date.day` and `date.weekday`

```
from datetime import  date

date1 = date(2005, 1, 1)
date2 = date(2008, 1, 1)

date1_ord = date1.toordinal()
date2_ord = date2.toordinal()
cnt = 0

for d_ord in range(date1_ord, date2_ord):
    d = date.fromordinal(d_ord)
    if (d.weekday() == 6) and (d.day == 1):
        cnt = cnt + 1

print("Number of Sunday 1'st days is {}".format(cnt))
```